# How to get ID of last saved(not recently saved) row in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning ASP.Net MVC with Entity Framework. I would like to get the id of last saved record. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667828/asp-net-mvc-get-id-of-last-added-record) and the accepted answer works fine when you would like to get id of the record you saved recently. I need the record which might have been saved two day earlier.

How do I retrieve this?

Comment: What do you use to store your data? Entity Framework? Why not just sort by descending Id and take the first record?

Comment: Yes. Entity framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to sort descending and then take the first record.

If you want the record, then this:

```
Person person = db.PersonTable.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First();
int personId = person.Id;
```

Or, you can select the id, like this:

```
int personId = db.PersonTable.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First().Id;
```

Answer (score 4):

like this but you will lose some performance

```
db.YourTable.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList().Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Entity Framework.

```
_context.Users.OrderByDescending(user => user.Id).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Max() like this:

```
db.SaveChanges();
int id = db.table.Max(i => i.myId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest if you want to find records specifically based on a date adding another column to the entity in question.

e.g. If you entity was 'OrderItem' I would have

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I would then write my LINQ statement....

```
var latestOrderItem = db.OrderItem.OrderByDescending(orderItem => orderItem.CreatedDateTime).First();
```

This should give me the latest item added.

```
var latestId = latestOrderItem.Id;
```